# An entry with the same key already exists? Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access, gridview

I have a gridview control on my page and any time I try to use the delete button that comes with it, it gives me the error mentioned above. Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="picPath" 
        DataImageUrlFormatString="PlaceImages/{0}" HeaderText="Picture"  ControlStyle-CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat">
        <ControlStyle CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PicPath" HeaderText="Filename" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" 
            SortExpression="Country" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.mdb" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Slides] WHERE [ID] = ?" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Slides] ([ID], [PicPath], [Title], [City], [Country]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Slides]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Slides] SET [PicPath] = ?, [Title] = ?, [City] = ?, [Country] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PicPath" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="PicPath" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

I actually had this problem with another page that had more stuff on it than just the gridview. I was curious if that had anything to do with it, so I just created a new page and copied just the datasource and gridview and it still gave me the same error. There are only 9 records in the table and there are certainly no duplicate PKs. Only the ID field is marked as the primary key in the table. What is going on?

Comment: can you post your delete button code.it seems that in your code you have a button to delete and you duplicate the key in the button name. so check that.@Joseph

Comment: It's up there. There's no code behind or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use question mark mentioned in command. Please make change as like below then it will work's fine

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Slides] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Slides] ([ID], [PicPath], [Title], [City], [Country]) VALUES (@ID, @PicPath, @Title, @City, @Country)" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Slides]" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Slides] SET [PicPath] = @PicPath, [Title] = @Title, [City] = @City, [Country] = @Country WHERE [ID] = @ID">
```

If in case your table ID having auto increment then don't use ID in insert command.

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Slides] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Slides] ([PicPath], [Title], [City], [Country]) VALUES ( @PicPath, @Title, @City, @Country)" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Slides]" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Slides] SET [PicPath] = @PicPath, [Title] = @Title, [City] = @City, [Country] = @Country WHERE [ID] = @ID">
```

Comment: Hey Mahesh, thanks for your suggestion, but it still gives me the same error. Also, I took out the insert command altogether because I'm not using at all in the code behind or the markup.

Comment: Code level it is fine.. Make sure the table is auto increment of primary key column.. This error is because already existing key your are trying to enter again in the table.. So delete all the records in the table and Modify the primary key column with auto increment then it will work...